# How to download all files from s3 bucket, when objects have Windows incompatible filenames

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Trying to copy everything in my s3 bucket to local harddisk using:

```
aws s3 cp s3://mybucket . --recursive
```

But contents of bucket is a log stream with object names like this:

```
logs/
├──2018-03-20/
│   ├──01:00+00/
│   │   └──01:10:06.521.csv.gz
│   ├──02:00+00/
│   │   └──02:22:09.306.csv.gz
etc
```

When I try to copy, I get nothing but empty folders with names like `logs/2018-03-20`. I'm guessing this is because Windows won't allow colons in folder or filenames, and the --recursive command doesn't auto-correct (when I download from a browser, the colons are replaced with underscores).

I don't have control of the log stream output.

Anyone have any suggestions for how to get all the data downloaded (besides manually file-by-file)? Is there any way to specify how filenames would be output from a `cp --recursive` or `sync` command?

Comment: You are correct, even an 'aws s3 sync' will choke on those files names. To do a recursive download without having to call out and rename each file, you'll have to use the AWS API. Being on windows, PowerShell or ( my personal favorite ) Python+BOTO would be the ticket... or use a virtual machine or docker container with a *nix os and the awscli installed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to setup a use-case with 'test:test' filename and download them using CyberDuck on a windows 10 virtual machine.
I just dragged the folder that contained the file and it renamed them on download.

You can download cyberduck here

https://cyberduck.io/

Cheers!