# Download S3 Objects that have Carriage Return in filename using CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

We have over 50k files with Carriage Return `\r` or `%0D` in filename. An example

```
    {
        "LastModified": "2021-12-25T20:33:05.000Z",
        "ETag": "\"653e05d2e10dffc122aa91a93b699413\"",
        "StorageClass": "STANDARD",
        "Key": "portalahm/zz9JDN3n.jpg\r",
        "Owner": {
            "ID": "e3fdea5553e3b1a5f37cea2df020a92c6a2efbadcdaf58a2589e930b85a95aff"
        },
        "Size": 1703936
    },
```

Can anyone suggest how to rename these files by removing that special character using CLI commands `aws s3 mv` or download them to Windows system using `s3api get-object` or `aws s3 cp`?

All the attempts of renaming using `mv` or downloading the objects is giving `Key does not exist` error.

TIA

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't quite recreate your situation with `\r`, but I managed to do it with `\n` by inserting a CR into an object key. So, here is a Python script that should be able to copy the files for you:

```py
import boto3

s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')

for object in s3_resource.Bucket('my-bucket').objects.all():
    if '\r' in object.key:
        new_object = s3_resource.Object(object.bucket_name, object.key.replace('\r', ''))
        new_object.copy({'Bucket': object.bucket_name, 'Key': object.key})
        print(object.key, new_object.key)
        # object.delete()  # Remove comment-marker to delete source object after copy
```

Comment: Thanks @John Rotenstein, I saw similar solution in another thread. Also [Cyberduck](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49375914/8541830) is able to solve the issue temporarily by replacing the special character with ```_``` which prompted a bulk rename post download. I was looking for a command line based approach that can be executed by non-techie. Of course, if none available, I'll use your script and give it to my non-techie friends.

Answer (score 0):

Use the script below to bulk rename files, it will trim file names with \r

```
#############################
# Configuration: 

bucketname = "YOUR_S3_BUCKET_NAME"
access_key = 'YOUR_ACCESS_KEY_ID'
secret_key = 'YOUR_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'

#############################

require 'rubygems'
require 'aws/s3'
include AWS::S3

Base.establish_connection!(
      :access_key_id     => access_key,
      :secret_access_key => secret_key
    )

b = Bucket.find(bucketname)
marker = ''
while b.size > 0 do
  puts "\n\n--------------------new page----------------------"
  puts "\n From marker #{marker}"
  puts "\n\n--------------------------------------------------"
  b.each {|s3o| 
    if s3o.key =~ /\r/i
      begin
        old_key = s3o.key
        new_key = s3o.key.gsub(/\r/i, '')

        S3Object.copy(old_key, new_key, bucketname)
        puts "copied #{old_key} to #{new_key}"

        #Uncomment this if you're feeling confident and want to delete the key
        #s3o.delete
      rescue Exception => e
        puts "\n\n @@@@@@@@@@@@ EXCEPTION on key #{s3o.key} \n\n"
        puts e.message
        puts "@@@@@@@@@@@@@@}"
        next
      end
      
    end
  }
  marker = b.objects.last.key
  b = Bucket.find('
```

Comment: Thanks @aws-ps. But, this requires Ruby. Is it not possible with Windows ```powershell``` or ```bash``` or similar shell scripting with additional parameters such ```--cli-input-json``` passed to ```s3api```? When ```list-objects``` is able to provide encoded ```url```, I wonder why one can't download using ```get-object```.

Comment: ruby is platform-independent like python or node, so you should be able to run it on any machine, if you don't have ruby you can install it  easily from here: https://rubyinstaller.org/

Comment: and if you name your file with .rb it will be executable and you can call it directly from your powershell or #!/usr/bin/envy ruby for linux